# Adb issue in androidviewclient

Tags: python, adb, androidviewclient

J have a issue with ADB. I execute a python script lasting about 10 hours, but often the script crashes with message "Is adb running on your computer?". 
To resolve this issue, I update adb with "adb devices" or "adb kill-server"+"adb start-server". Despite this, the script crashes.  I try also to kill PID with "kill -9 PID_NUMBER", but the issue isn't solve.

Comment: Is `adb` actually crashing or losing the connection to your device? Is the script doing something special that may cause it to crash? Can you monitor adb or collect some logs to try to understand what's happening?

Comment: Adb loses connection. No the script doesn't anything special.  Actually when I see adb process in running, sometimes adb server disconnectes to 5037 port. I work on Ubuntu Linux with android SDK installed. So I think that the problem is with adb installation. Is it a special driver with adb in linux ubuntu ? Like in windows.

Comment: No special driver needed. Are you sure you have on,y one adb installed (`which adb`)?

Comment: I have Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32 Revision debian on an Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: here `$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 0.0.1-4500957
Installed as /home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: use the one from the sdk, not the package

Comment: Can you give me the link where I can download this version ?

Comment: I have installed Adb 1.0.39 Version 0.0.1-04500957 but when I execute my script I have a RuntimeError: Incorrect ADB Server version 0004027 (expecting one of ['00040024', '00040023', '00040020','0004001f']). How can I resolve this bug ?

Comment: What's the device and android version?

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) latest version already includes support for ADB Server version 0004027.

```
VALID_ADB_VERSIONS = ["00040027", "00040024", "00040023", "00040020", "0004001f"]
```

You are using an older version, please upgrade to the latest **version 13.6.2**:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/androidviewclient
- https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/releases/tag/v13.6.2

Comment: I have always the same issue even with androidviewclient 13.6.2 + adb 1.0.39. After a few hours, devices disconnect to pc with "Is adb running on your computer ?" message on Pc. But when I tap "adb devices" the serial number of devices are connected but on devices screen pop up "allow access to device data" appears.

Comment: Does it happen only with a specific device? In any case, it seems more like an adb or device than AVC issue. Try latest AVC (15.3.1) to see if the issue is still reproducible.